# adding new column to the existing table in sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, database-migration, sequelize.js

I have a table in the database and now I want to add two new columns to it.
I have altered the Table using the `MYSQL cmd line` and also added the newly added columns into the `Sequelize` model.

But when I fire the insert query, it still fires the query with previous fields and does not adds up the newly added columns to it.

Here is my data Model:

```
var Observation = sequelize.define('observation_details', {
  obv_id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    primaryKey: true
  },
  obv_source: Sequelize.STRING,
  obv_waveband: Sequelize.INTEGER,
  prpsl_id: Sequelize.INTEGER,
  obv_ra: Sequelize.DOUBLE,              //newly added column
  obv_dec: Sequelize.DOUBLE              // newly added column
}, {
  tableName: 'observation_details',             
  timestamps: false                             
});
```

[image: This is how the datable looks in the Database]

Here in the table `obv_ra` and `obv_dec` are already added..!

This is the Insert Query:

```
Observation.create({
  obv_source: req.body.obvDetails[i].source,
  obv_waveband: req.body.obvDetails[i].waveband,
  prpsl_id: proposalId,
  obv_ra: req.body.obvDetails[i].ra,
  obv_dec: req.body.obvDetails[i].dec
})
```

adding `Sequelize.sync({force:false})` results in :

> Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS observation_details (obv_id INTEGER , obv_source VARCHAR(255), obv_waveband INTEGER, prpsl_id INTEGER, obv_ra DOUBLE PRECISION, obv_dec DOUBLE PRECISION, PRIMARY KEY (obv_id)) ENGINE=InnoDB;

but still the query fired is :

> Executing (default): INSERT INTO observation_details (obv_id,obv_source,obv_waveband,prpsl_id) VALUES (NULL,dgf,2,19);

Is there any way to work this out without using `Migrations`?

Comment: Use [sync](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/schema/#syncing) - might help. Maybe there is a difference between Model and db - you will see it with `sync`. Be careful and backup the database before using it, as `force` will make drop the tables.

Comment: what if I set `force:false` , is there anyway this can be done without dropping the table

Comment: @AndreyPopov please see my edit

Answer (score 1):

I suppose there is if you're willing to lose all data, you can delete and start from scratch again.

You can also do some fancy logic before the create to check the schema of the table on disk vs what you expect it to be from the model and add/remove columns as appropriate, but at that point you're just reimplementing a less flexible version of `Migrations`. Unless there's a compelling reason not to, you should use `Migrations`.